# What does Add DROP SYNTAX in X-Cloner of Wordpress mean?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

What does "Add DROP SYNTAX" in the XCloner plugin mean?

[image]

I checked the manual and it says something I don't understand.

> Add MySQL Drop: 
>   Tick this checkbox if you want XCloner to add the DROP TABLE IF
>   EXISTS statement to your generated SQL. This option is only for
>   advanced users.

How important is this to check? and will I lose anything if I ignore it? Please explain in both short and long answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable this option, the resulting exported SQL will contain `DROP TABLE IF EXIST` statements. This means that when you try and import said SQL into another database, it will DROP any existing tables that have the same names as the tables contained in the SQL. If I export the tables `users`, `items` and `news` from `Database A` and I attempt to import them into `Database B`, any tables with those names will be dropped before those three tables are imported. So, if I already have a table called `users` in `Database B`, it will be dropped before the "new" `users` table is imported. Could be disastrous if you have another app connected to `Database B` that also uses its own table called `users`.

Comment: So enabling this option is a kind of "overwrite" permission? So if enable this, it will not merge the data, but will delete and take over. Right?

Comment: That's basically what it does. It's like selecting the overwrite option when you're copying files.

Comment: But why is this being set while doing the backup and not while doing the restore? It somehow doesn't make sense, don't you think?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Dropping an old table and creating a new table with the latest data is easier than trying to figure out what rows have been deleted/updated etc since the last backup. It is being set during the backup because it is easier to create the SQL there and then.